# How do you get a click function to work independantly

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I wonder if you can help me.

I am using the below code and wanted to know if anyone know how to get the function in the JS to work independently on UL's rather interfering with each other.

Basically when the page loads it calls the JS function which checks the inputs on the form for the checked radio button and applies a specific CSS class to set styles and highlight to it's parent LI in the HTML mark-up. It also works out from the click event if you choose another option in the radio button list to remove any styles that may have been applied to any LI's and put the class on the corresponding parent LI of the option you have clicked on

Now the problem lies is that as I am checking it against a form (which houses the UL and children LI's that contain the radio button list) where there are two different radio button lists which breaks the code as it doesn't know which UL in the form to apply the code to. It works fine if I only have one UL so really I need the JS to be a bit more 'cleverer' and run on the corresponding UL that I have clicked on and not affect the other. I still want it to highlight the checked radio button on both lists on page load though

Would greatly appreciate any help.

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
   <ul id="activityChoices" class="radioList">
      <li class="radio-item">
          <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="radio1">
          <label for="radio1">radio1</label>
      </li>
      <li class="radio-item">
          <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" value="radio2">
          <label for="radio2">radio2</label>
      </li>
      <li class="radio-item">
          <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" value="radio3" checked="checked">
          <label for="radio3" >radio3</label>
      </li>
      <li class="radio-item">
          <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="radio" value="radio4">
          <label for="radio4" >radio4</label>
      </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
      <li>
          <input type="radio" id="yes" name="answer" value="yes">
          <label for="yes">yes</label>
      </li>
      <li>
          <input type="radio" id="no" name="answer" value="no">
          <label for="no">no</label>
      </li>
  </ul>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    highlightSelectedRadio('myForm','input');
</script>
```

JS:

```
function highlightSelectedRadio(myForm, tag) 
{
  var form = document.getElementById(myForm);
  var inputArray = form.getElementsByTagName(tag);
  var prevClass = null;

  for (i=0;i<inputArray.length;i++) {
    if(inputArray[i].checked) {
      prevClass = inputArray[i].parentNode.getAttribute("class");
      inputArray[i].parentNode.className += " myclass";
    }   
  }

  var myArray = form.getElementsByClassName("myclass");
  form.onclick = function() {
    for (j=0;j<myArray.length;j++) {
      myArray[j].className = prevClass;
    }
    inputArray = this.getElementsByTagName(tag);

    for (i=0;i<inputArray.length;i++) {
      if(inputArray[i].checked) {
        inputArray[i].parentNode.className += " myclass";
      }   
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please expand on this "how to get the function in the JS to work independently on UL's rather interfering with each other." - it is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: Do you insist on not using a library? (ie. jQuery, prototype, etc)

Comment: Yes, I do really.  I know JQuery and other libraries are quite powerful and makes the code more trimmer but I cannot introduce other libraries so my hands are tied on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I think this is what you need:

```
function highlightSelectedRadio(myForm, tag) 
{
    var form = document.getElementById(myForm);
    var radios = form.getElementsByTagName(tag);

    for (var i=0, l = radios.length;i < l; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            addClass(radios[i].parentNode, 'myclass');
        }
    }

    form.onclick = function() {
        for (var i = 0, l = radios.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (radios[i].checked) {
                addClass(radios[i].parentNode, 'myclass');
            } else {
                removeClass(radios[i].parentNode, 'myclass');
            }
        }
    };
}

function addClass(el, c) {
    if (el.className.indexOf(c) === -1) {
        el.className += ' myclass';
    }
}
function removeClass(el, c) {
    var re = new RegExp(' ?' + c + ' ?');
    el.className = el.className.replace(re, '');
}
```

Comment: Thanks dreavor.  I've had a shot at this script.  It's great but there is still one problem, it still doesn't recognise the parent UL in relation to which radio list you have clicked on when there is two UL lists on the page.  So it is breaking when you choose a different option in the second radio list

Comment: I've created a jsFiddle page here: http://jsfiddle.net/5xkwW/ It seems to work ok from what I understood: the radios are highlighted separately. Could you have a look and let me know what you'd like different?

Comment: I've had a look in jsFiddle and it's getting near to what I want.  One bugette that I noticed with is that if you click on the 'Yes' option first in the second radio list and then the 'No' option, the red background stays highlighted on 'Yes'

Comment: The above code is correct, but the jsFiddle had an old version. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/5xkwW/1/ I've pasted the above code and it works without problems.